# Multiply each column of 2d array and return array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multiplication

New to JS here. How can I use math.js or vanilla js to return an array where a 2d array is multiplied by each column. The size of the 2 arrays will always be the same.

```
[[2,2],
[2,4]]
```

results is

```
[4,8]
```

I have tried:

```
adjustedrating = [[2,2],[2,4]]
var w = adjustedrating.length;

for (var i = 0, len = adjustedrating[0].length; i < len; i++) {
  var multiple = adjustedrating[0][i];
  for (var j = 0; j < w; j++) {
      multiple *= adjustedrating[j][i];

  }
  both.push(multiple);
};
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is loop through the outer array, and store the results of the multiplication as you go. For instance:

```js
// The two dimensional array
var twoDimArray = [[2,2],
                   [2,4]];

// We'll say this is where your results will go. It will be the same length
//     as one of your inner arrays, and all values will start at 1
var results = [1,1];

// Loop through the 2D Array
for( var outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < twoDimArray.length; outerIndex++){
    // Loop through the currently selected inner array
    for( var innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < twoDimArray[outerIndex].length; innerIndex++){
        // Multiply appropriate result by the appropriate value
        results[innerIndex] *= twoDimArray[outerIndex][innerIndex];
    }
}

// Simply displays the results somewhere
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = results;
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Please clarify.

Comment: My apologies. Code was not included initially and thought user has not given any efforts. I'll delete my comment. Also I'd suggest using forEach.